# Get-ChildItem with CreationTime instead of LastWriteTime?

Tags: powershell

if you use `Get-ChildItem` you get something like

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----          3/1/2006   9:03 AM            Bluetooth Software
d---s         5/10/2006   8:55 AM            Cookies
d----          5/9/2006   2:09 PM            Desktop
```

Thats fine. I just want now to change the **LastWriteTime** output to **CreationTime**. Everything else should be the same. Any ideas?

Comment: did you misspell CreationTime or did you mean to actually replace LastWriteTime with CreatingTime?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can select it with `Select-Object` or any of the `Format-*` cmdlets

```
Get-ChildItem | Select-Object Mode,CreationTime,Length,Name
```

Answer (score 5):

For one-off changes to displayed columns, piping to `select` or `Format-Table` is easiest.  If you want to make this a persistent change, you need to deal with the format files which govern how powershell displays filesystem objects.

Editing the existing format file (likely at `$env:SystemRoot\system32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\FileSystem.format.ps1xml`) is not recommended, since that file has a signature block at the bottom.  Changing the file content will invalidate the signature, which can cause problems.

Instead, you can define your own format file which will override the default one.  Save the below file as `FileFormat.format.ps1xml` and run

`Update-FormatData -Prepend c:\FileFormat.format.ps1xml`

By default, `CreationTime` will be shown, not `LastWriteTime`.

Format file content (copied from real format file, just changed the relevant bits):

```
<Configuration>
    <SelectionSets>
        <SelectionSet>
            <Name>FileSystemTypes</Name>
            <Types>
                <TypeName>System.IO.DirectoryInfo</TypeName>
                <TypeName>System.IO.FileInfo</TypeName>
            </Types>
        </SelectionSet>
    </SelectionSets>
    <ViewDefinitions>
       <View>
            <Name>children</Name>
            <ViewSelectedBy>
                <SelectionSetName>FileSystemTypes</SelectionSetName>
            </ViewSelectedBy>
            <GroupBy>
                <PropertyName>PSParentPath</PropertyName> 
                <CustomControlName>FileSystemTypes-GroupingFormat</CustomControlName>  
            </GroupBy>
            <TableControl>
                <TableHeaders>
                   <TableColumnHeader>
                      <Label>Mode</Label>
                      <Width>7</Width>
                      <Alignment>left</Alignment>
                   </TableColumnHeader>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Label>CreationTime</Label>
                        <Width>25</Width>
                        <Alignment>right</Alignment>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Label>Length</Label>
                        <Width>10</Width>
                        <Alignment>right</Alignment>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                    <TableColumnHeader/>
                </TableHeaders>
                <TableRowEntries>
                    <TableRowEntry>
                        <Wrap/>
                        <TableColumnItems>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <PropertyName>Mode</PropertyName>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <ScriptBlock>
                                    [String]::Format("{0,10}  {1,8}", $_.CreationTime.ToString("d"), $_.CreationTime.ToString("t"))
                                </ScriptBlock>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                            <PropertyName>Length</PropertyName>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <PropertyName>Name</PropertyName>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                        </TableColumnItems>
                    </TableRowEntry>
                </TableRowEntries>
            </TableControl>
        </View>
    </ViewDefinitions>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you meant that you wanted to show the property CreationTime instead of LastWriteTime, then you could pipe the output of Get-ChildItem to Select-Object and specify which properties to select:

```
Get-ChildItem | Select Mode, CreationTime, Length, Name
```

Answer (score 3):

in V3 you can use dynamic type data:

```
    PS III> # UNTESTED: if work...you can paste this in your profile
    PS III>
    PS III> Update-TypeData -TypeName System.IO.FileInfo,System.IO.DirectoryInfo -MemberName DFPR DefaultDisplayPropertySet Mode,CreationTime,Length,Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try
`> get-childitem | sort-object -property name, creationtime, lastwritetime`

You will see like this in PowerShell:

```
 Directory: C:\project\CNN I\Maya                             

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name 
----                 -------------         ------ ---- 
-a----         1/11/2021  11:36 PM          32187 ocean wake foam.JPG                                                   
-a----          1/6/2021  12:28 AM         121100 ocean_clean.ma                                                        
-a----          1/4/2021   3:59 PM         122199 ocean_clean_1.ma
```

You don't see Date Created, but it actually is sorted by Name and Date Created (`creationtime`) and then Date Modified (`lastwritetime`). If you want to verify this, please try `> get-childitem | sort-object lastwritetime`. It will list the files by Date Modified.